# Is it safe to delete a binary in /usr/bin?

Tags: linux, command-line, rm, binary, delete

I installed the precompiled binary of a command line program in `/usr/bin`, now I want to install the same program using my package manager. In order to avoid conflict between the package manager `dnf` and the precompiled binary in `/usr/bin` I want to remove the precompiled binary beforehand using `rm -i`.

I usually let `dnf` handle removal of programs installed in `/usr/bin` so before I try removing a `/usr/bin` binary myself I want to know if it is safe to `rm -i` a program installed in `/usr/bin`? Are there any risks of removing a program manually from `/usr/bin`?

Comment: Make sure it's not a replacement of key components of your system, or as you can figure it out, you just deleted that key components

Answer (score 4):

If it was installed manually, there's no problem in removing it manually.

For the future, it is a good idea to put manually-installed (i.e. not managed by the package manager) binaries in a subdir of `/opt`; for small programs you can even create a `/opt/bin` and put them there. This to avoid confusion.

Comment: I recommend using `/usr/local/bin`.  If using `/opt/bin`, make sure to add it to $PATH.  Using `/usr/bin` for user binaries is considered as a bad practice and highly discouraged, as it is usually reserved for distribution-managed binaries.

Comment: thanks for confirming. I installed that program when I was new to linux so I didn't think of separating binary installation directories for the package manager (in `/usr/bin`) and manual installations (in `/usr/local/bin` or `/opt`). Fortunately I realised that using `/usr/bin` for user (i.e. manually installed) binaries is bad practice in time to install all other manually installed binaries in `/usr/local/bin` or `/opt`. @otter.pro thanks for the reminder to add `/opt/bin` to $PATH if it exists